# How to do to remove the word after removing a stroke, a word is in a text file each sentence well a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

file content:

```
this is a simple example of app-

lying translinelation rules
```

my code:

```
arq = open('speech.txt', 'r') 
line = ar.read().replace('-','').split()
print(line)
```

Exit from my code:

```
 ['this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'example', 'of', ***'app', 'lying'***, 'translinelation', 'rules']
```

correct output:

```
 ['this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'example', 'of', *'**applying'**,* 'translinelation', 'rules']
```

I highlighted the word that happened the error.

```
 applying
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: if you invoke `split()` without arguments it will split the string on spaces, tabs and newlines.

Comment: hello daniela, I can not do it for a text with 7 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also replace the new line:

```
content = "this is a simple example of app-\nlying translinelation rules"
line = content.replace('-\n','').split()
print(line)
```

https://repl.it/repls/JollyFamiliarQbasic

Comment: friend for a 2 line text the code worked perfectly, I tried with a 7 line text but it did not work.